# GeoServer tilesorigin and Meta-tiling

Tags: geoserver, openlayers, wms

I'm trying to understand tilesorigin and Meta-tiling in GeoServer.

The [docs](https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/services/wms/vendor.html#tilesorigin) state that `tilesorigin=x,y` where x and y are the coordinates of the lower left corner (the “origin”) of the tile grid system.

And gives (OpenLayers 2) example: `tilesorigin: map.maxExtent.left + ',' + map.maxExtent.bottom`

Is the equivalent for modern OpenLayers either one of the below?
`ol.extent.getBottomLeft(ol.proj.get('EPSG:3857').getExtent()).toString()`
`ol.extent.getBottomLeft(map.getView().getProjection().getExtent()).toString()`

How do I know if meta-tiling is actually working? Tiling and caching of tiles works fine without setting `tilesorigin`.

What is a logic of requiring the client sets `tiled=true` and `tilesorigin` to enable meta-tiling? If one client makes requests with `tilesorigin` omitted (meta-tiling disabled), and the tiles that are generated are cached, and a different client makes requests with `tilesorigin` set correctly (meta-tiling enabled), the second client will just get back the cached tiles created by the first client, and not get the benefit of meta-tiling?

If GeoServer knows a client making requests with `srs=EPSG:3857`, and bottomleft of EPSG:3857 is always the same, why doesn't it just figure out tilesorigin itself, and not rely on the client correctly setting it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These parameters are a hack put in to help early WMS clients get the benefit of tiles with out them having to understand the WMTS standard.

You shouldn't need to use them these days as OpenLayers and Leaflet (and most other clients) understand WMTS and TMS tiling. So, they can make requests in a better fashion that GeoServer (GeoWebCache) understands with out any effort at either end.